# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz

Tags: virtualbox

I'm trying to install lxml on a virtual machine running ubuntu/trusty64 in a virtualenv however i get this error below and can't get my head around it.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
```

the first time this error occurred i looked into installing lz. i installed it using sudo apt-get install mtools which contains lz however the error still occurs therefore i'm thinking this could be a symbolic link problem maybe a file is supposed to be linked to lz but not sure what file. lz has a symlink to uz but i dont know what effect that has and don't want to change that incase it breaks something else. any ideas to point me in the right direction?

```
building 'lxml.etree' extension

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/lxml

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/libxml2 -Isrc/lxml/includes -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -lxslt -lexslt -lxml2 -lz -lm -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/etree.so

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/devenv/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/devenv/build/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-yUqdLy-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/devenv/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/devenv/build/lxml
Storing debug log for failure in /home/vagrant/.pip/pip.log

(devenv)vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant/woowoo/woowoo_webapp$ ls -l /usr/bin/ld
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 6 Sep 16 16:11 /usr/bin/ld -> ld.bfd
(devenv)$ vim /usr/bin/ld.bfd 
(devenv)$ ls -l /usr/bin/ld.bfd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1050912 Sep 16 16:10 /usr/bin/ld.bfd
(devenv)$ ls -l /usr/bin/ld
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 6 Sep 16 16:11 /usr/bin/ld -> ld.bfd
(devenv)$ ls -l /usr/bin/lzlrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 2 Oct 10  2013 /usr/bin/lz -> uz
(devenv)$ ls -l /usr/bin/uz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2496 Oct 10  2013 /usr/bin/uz
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to install the build dependencies of lxml in order to compile it. Try doing `sudo apt-get build-dep python-lxml` if you have source package data enabled in your apt sources.

What is missing is not the `lz` command, but the development files for the zlib library. You need to install `zlib1g-dev` to get this.

Comment: perfect that did the trick! i didn't know about building dependancies in order to compile but that makes perfect sense. thanks for teaching me something and solving my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try one of those three :

1. `sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev`
2. `sudo apt-get install libz-dev`
3. `sudo apt-get install lib32z1-dev`

wish will work for you 
reference to [“/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373995/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lz) for more details.